# How to watch rss feed for new entries from bash script?

Tags: command-line, scripting, rss-aggregator

I need to watch a RSS feed from our hudson ci server.
Each time a new entry is available i want to play a sound by calling `#>play sound.wav`.

Does anyone know a tool which can watch a rss-feed and fire a command each time a new entry appears?

I had a look at `rsstail` but it gets all entries from the feed and not the latest or only the ones that are new since the last lookup.

Comment: Maybe you can modify bashpodder.shell? (http://lincgeek.org/bashpodder/)

Comment: Are you sure you are using `rsstail` correctly? Its [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/oneiric/man1/rsstail.1.html) says thet the default interval of checking for new feeds is 15 minutes and it can be changed by the `-i` parameter. (Remember that by RSS design, you'll never get the update information instantly, you have to poll.)

Comment: hell yeah. **rsstail -i 3 -u http://example.com/rss.xml -n 0** thats it. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thats the solution:

```
rsstail -i 3 -u example.com/rss.xml -n 0 | while read x ; do play fail.ogg ; done
```

so each time a new topic is released in the feed, the sound will be played.
play is packaged in sox

Comment: I understand that this solves the part about refreshing, but is not (yet) a way to play sound (the main part you asked for). If you solved it as well, please write how.

Comment: your right. just updating ...

Answer (score 10):

You can try using **[Newsbeuter](http://www.newsbeuter.org/index.html)** which has an option to run an external command (see `notify-program` [in the documentation](http://www.newsbeuter.org/doc/newsbeuter.html)).

**[Canto](http://www.codezen.org/canto/)** also has some customizable *hooks*, though the whole configuration system looks a bit more complicated at first glance.

With `rsstail` + shell you can also invoke external commands. Start off with what you already figured out:

```
rsstail -i 3 -u example.com/rss.xml -n 0
```

and pipe the output to a `while read` loop:

```
rsstail -i 3 -u example.com/rss.xml -n 0 | while read line
  do
    aplay /some/sound/file.wav
    echo "$line"
  done
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
#!/bin/bash
last=""
while true
do
    now="$(curl http://yourdomain/feed.rss 2> /dev/null | grep pubDate | head -1)"
    test "$last" != "$now" && play mysound.wav
    last="$now"
    sleep 1m
done
```